# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'complex' error while both are complex

Tags: python, operators, complex-numbers

I'm getting an error with an operand comparing 2 complex numbers. I'm sure both are complex numbers because when I hover the variables in VS Code it clearly says 'Complex' in every instance.

So I created the following class

```
class Snake(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [random.randint(1, (width-sqr_size)/sqr_size)*sqr_size,
                    random.randint(1, (height-sqr_size)/sqr_size)*sqr_size]
        self.mov = 1 + 0j
        self.body = [self.pos[:]]

    def move(self, key): #Snake movement
        if key + self.mov != 0 + 0j:
            self.mov = copy.copy(key)
        self.pos += self.mov*SPEED
        self.body.insert(0, self.pos[:])
```

and the following function

```
def whatkey(event):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            return (-1 + 0j)
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            return (1 + 0j)
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            return (0 + 1j)
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            return (0 - 1j)
```

I call them like this

```
key1 = 0 + 0j
key1 = whatkey(event)
snake.move(key1)
```

The problem is supposedly in the operation '+' in `if copy.copy(key) + self.mov != 0 + 0j:`

When I try to run my game, the following error in the title appears.
`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'complex'`

I don't understand, key1 is ALWAYS a complex number, it's never a None

Comment: And if `event.type` is not `pygame.KEYDOWN`?

Comment: @Ry- EDIT: I misunderstood. It's inside the usual even loop of for event in pygame.event.get()

Comment: `whatkey` returns a complex value only in the circumstances you’ve defined. If it doesn’t hit a return, it returns `None`. That happens when the event isn’t a `KEYDOWN` event or when the key isn’t an arrow key.

Comment: Never rely on VS to debug.  It is only telling you the "expected" variable type.  Use print statements and check types by print(type(variable)) in the code just prior to your statement that is giving you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows and you will see your error:

```
def whatkey(event):
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        return (-1 + 0j)
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        return (1 + 0j)
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        return (0 + 1j)
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        return (0 - 1j)
    print("event.key is ", event.key)
    print("Crap... I have to return None!")
    # code ends now and python returns whatkey(event) = None
```

Comment: just added a default return and that fixed it. Thanks! I forgot it had to return something, I just assumed it skipped.